# How to tell Jackson not to include collection type information?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've run into the "Polymorphic deserialization problem", so I'm configuring jackson to add type information for non-concrete classes as a property as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE))
mapper.enableDefaultTypingAsProperty(DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS, "__class__")
```

It works well, but for collection instances (List for example) it creates a two-element array with the first position holding an string with the type information of the collection (java.util.ArrayList).

This affects the structure of the json the client (Javascript) is expecting, since where it expected an array, now there's an array with another inside it at the second position.

I wish Jackson insert type information only for non-collection not concrete types, since the framework itself doesn't need the collection implementation type in order to deserialize collection properties correctly.

Is this possible in configurable way?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom version of `ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder` and override the useForType() method.

Here's the implementation of the default method:

```
    public boolean useForType(JavaType t)
    {
        switch (_appliesFor) {
        case NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS:
            while (t.isArrayType()) {
                t = t.getContentType();
            }
            // fall through
        case OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE:
            return (t.getRawClass() == Object.class) || !t.isConcrete();
        case NON_FINAL:
            while (t.isArrayType()) {
                t = t.getContentType();
            }
            return !t.isFinal(); // includes Object.class
        default:
        //case JAVA_LANG_OBJECT:
            return (t.getRawClass() == Object.class);
        }
    }
```

In your version, just add this precondition

```
if (t.isCollectionLikeType()) {
    return false;
}
```

to tell Jackson to skip Collection-like types for inserting type information.

And set your new `TypeResolverBuilder` with `ObjectMapper.setDefaultTyping(myCustomTyper);`